# How can I speed up this directory walk?

Tags: python, os.walk, scandir

I'm trying to write a function that finds a directory by traversing a directory tree with `os.walk()` below. On my machine, this takes 15 seconds.

```
for dir_path, dir_names, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~')):
    for dir_name in dir_names:
        if dir_name == 'some_dir':
            path = os.path.join(dir_path, dir_name)
            print(path)
```

I read that `os.scandir()` is faster so I tried this below, though I think the implementation is wrong. It works but it's now nearly 30 seconds.

```
for dir_path, dir_names, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~')):
    with os.scandir(dir_path) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.name.endswith('some_dir') and entry.is_dir():
                print(entry.path)
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: `os.scandir()` needs to be used __instead of__ `os.walk()` if you want it to have a chance to make anything faster. Using it _in addition_ means you're loading names in from the operating system twice -- once from `os.walk()` with its usual performance, and another time from `os.scandir()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as far as I know, `os.scandir()` is a replacement for `os.listdir()`, so it returns an iterator over the elements of a directory, but not recursively. So if replacing `os.walk()` it would only return the elements in the `home`-folder, but not in the subdirectories.

Comment: Right, so you'd need to call it multiple times, once per directory that gets recursed into -- just like `os.walk()` does under the hood. Whereas if your version of Python has an `os.walk()` that uses `scandir` instead of `listdir` already out-of-the-box, there may not be a lot of additional headroom there.

Comment: ...the thing to remember here is that `listdir` and `scandir` are primitives, and `walk` is a higher-level API built on top of those primitives (or others like them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @Jakob So basically there's not more I can do here to improve performance? The reason I'm doing this is that the folder `some_dir` is located in different places on different machines, so I'm trying to write generic code to find it.

Comment: Doing a full directory scan is _always_ slow -- that's why folks generally prefer to use `locate` instead of `find` where feasible. And `find` does a lot of tricky low-level optimization under the hood.

Comment: ...if there's a limited set of places where `some_dir` is most likely to be, I'd strongly advise writing code that's aware of that and prioritizes those locations before falling back to a broader scan (if not just requiring the user to tell you where the resources you need are, which is not exactly unheard of or rare).

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to replace the `for dir_name in dir_names` part:

```
for dir_path, dir_names, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~'):
    if 'some_dir' in dir_names:
        path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'some_dir')
        print(path)
```

I do not know if you have lots of subdirectories, but depending on that, this should already make the code faster.

Additionally, I would suggest to comment out th

The `os.scandir()` function is preferred over `os.listdir`, when you need additional information of the file type, but as `dir_names` only contains the directories of the subfolder, this is additional overhead you produce by calling that function, hence it is a lot slower than the original code.

If you use a python version `>=3.5`, then `os.walk()` already calls `os.scandir()` under the hood. As Charles Duffy already mentioned, individually calling `os.scandir()` recursively will most likely not be much faster.

Comment: You're right that `for dir_name in dir_names` was redundant, but removing this line didn't show any speed improvements.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you to read the comments from Charles. If for example the `'some_dir'` directory is located only in one of `['Documents', 'Downloads', 'data']`, then it might be much faster to only `os.walk()` over them, instead of the whole `home` folder.